# Kryo library has "overlapping classes" warning in maven shade-package phase

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin, kryo, uberjar

I am trying to create a shaded jar file but the shade plugin is giving me warnings.
I am not sure how to fix them.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>example.shade.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproj-shade-kryo</artifactId>
    <name>myproj-shade-kryo</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esotericsoftware.kryo</groupId>
            <artifactId>kryo</artifactId>
            <version>2.21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <DependencyConvergence/>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And the warning is:

```
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.4.2:shade (package) @ myproj-shade-kryo ---
[INFO] Including com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.21 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm:jar:shaded:1.07 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2 in the shaded jar.
[WARNING] minlog-1.2.jar, kryo-2.21.jar define 2 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - com.esotericsoftware.minlog.Log
[WARNING]   - com.esotericsoftware.minlog.Log$Logger
[WARNING] reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar, kryo-2.21.jar define 23 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes
[WARNING]   - com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.AccessClassLoader
[WARNING]   - com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.Label
[WARNING]   - com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter
[WARNING]   - com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.AnnotationVisitor
[WARNING]   - com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.Type
[WARNING]   - com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.FieldAccess
[WARNING]   - com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.ConstructorAccess
[WARNING]   - com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
[WARNING]   - com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.Edge
[WARNING]   - 13 more...
[WARNING] objenesis-1.2.jar, kryo-2.21.jar define 32 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase
[WARNING]   - org.objenesis.instantiator.gcj.GCJInstantiator
[WARNING]   - org.objenesis.ObjenesisHelper
[WARNING]   - org.objenesis.instantiator.jrockit.JRockitLegacyInstantiator
[WARNING]   - org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator
[WARNING]   - org.objenesis.instantiator.ObjectInstantiator
[WARNING]   - org.objenesis.instantiator.gcj.GCJInstantiatorBase$DummyStream
[WARNING]   - org.objenesis.instantiator.basic.ObjectStreamClassInstantiator
[WARNING]   - org.objenesis.ObjenesisException
[WARNING]   - org.objenesis.Objenesis
[WARNING]   - 22 more...
[WARNING] maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are
[WARNING] present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only one
[WARNING] single version of the class is copied to the uber jar.
[WARNING] Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these warnings,
[WARNING] otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on
[WARNING] mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output.
[WARNING] See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
```

I tried the `mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true` too but that does not give me any clues how to fix:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myproj-shade-kryo 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myproj-shade-kryo ---
[INFO] example.shade.group:myproj-shade-kryo:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.21:compile
[INFO]    +- com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm:jar:shaded:1.07:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Well for example `reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar` and  `kryo-2.21.jar` both bring the "same" classes, i.e. same fully qualified name. So you need to decide which one you exclude to fix this. If they come from transitive dependency, exclude it. Otherwise, select the content with [include/exclude](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html).

Comment: Wont this be a problem if I exclude one of the dependencies based on lower/higher version alone?

Comment: I think the right behavior here should be the ability to repackage dependencies which have different versions. So foo.bar.HelloWorld should become foo.bar.one.HelloWorld for version 1 and foo.bar.two.HelloWorld for version 2. For dependencies with same version, its not a problem anyways.

Comment: (Thinking aloud) It seems very strange that `reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar` and `kryo-2.21.jar` both define classes in the same package with the same name. Wouldn't `kryo-2.21` have noticed this when doing their own builds? Same classes with same package names as the dependencies should be very rare IMHO. Example: Why would kryo declare `org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase` in their own code base?

Comment: I'm afraid only the developers of that library could answer that one...

Comment: I added `kryo` tag to the question :)

Comment: @radistao I don't believe this is a duplicate. Kryo is doing something very unusual for a maven build: they're including classes from a completely different open source project (objenesis) but not shading/renaming them.

Comment: you are right: removed duplication flag and added description to the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42628444/907576

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem in `kryo-2.21`, seems to be fixed in `kryo-2.22`.

Behind the scene:

`kryo-2.21` package contains:

- com
- META-INF
- **org/objenesis/***
- minlog-1.2.jar
- **objenesis-1.2.jar**
- reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar

and `objenesis-1.2.jar` itself contains:

- META-INF
- **org/objenesis/***

So, both root `kryo` and inner `objenesis-1.2.jar` archives contain *org/objenesis/** classes!

Same for `reflectasm` library: it is included as the classes directly to `kryo/com/*` and as a jar `kryo/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar`

This seems to be fixed in `kryo-2.22`, [guess this `minimizeJar` build property makes the effect](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/compare/241af2f7d9d77771dbaca919bd155057bad7c626...cd7a3516e50f1736a9edc3133284291a73f87354#diff-600376dffeb79835ede4a0b285078036R126)

For other cases how to exclude overlapping from multiple libraries see [Maven build [WARNING] we have a duplicate class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802736/maven-build-warning-we-have-a-duplicate-class/)

Also some times (if you are sure there is no overlapping classes in your dependencies) - try to clean the project:

`mvn clean package`