# How to avoid the "Overlappping classes" warning in a maven build?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have a module which have dependency on other two projects but I am getting this when building projects with.

Although no error is coming, but I am getting lots of warning for overlapping the same class:

```
[WARNING] commons-logging-1.2.jar, jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar define 6 overlappping classes: 
[WARNING]   - org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1
[WARNING]   - org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[WARNING]   - org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
[WARNING]   - org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException
[WARNING]   - org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog
[WARNING]   - org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[WARNING] aspectjrt-1.7.0.jar, aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar define 128 overlappping classes: 
[WARNING]   - org.aspectj.internal.lang.reflect.SignaturePatternImpl
[WARNING]   - org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.SignatureImpl
[WARNING]   - org.aspectj.internal.lang.reflect.DeclareSoftImpl
[WARNING]   - org.aspectj.lang.reflect.AjType
[WARNING]   - org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint$StaticPart
[WARNING]   - org.aspectj.runtime.internal.cflowstack.ThreadStackImpl11
[WARNING]   - org.aspectj.runtime.internal.cflowstack.ThreadStack
[WARNING]   - org.aspectj.internal.lang.reflect.InterTypeDeclarationImpl
[WARNING]   - org.aspectj.internal.lang.reflect.DeclareAnnotationImpl
[WARNING]   - org.aspectj.lang.annotation.SuppressAjWarnings
[WARNING]   - 118 more...
[WARNING] maven-shade-plugin has detected that some .class files
[WARNING] are present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only
[WARNING] one single version of the class is copied in the uberjar.
[WARNING] Usually this is not harmful and you can skeep these
[WARNING] warnings, otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts
[WARNING] based on mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above
[WARNING] output
[WARNING] See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Shade+Plugin
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
```

How can I avoid those warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Maven plugin Dependency Tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html), and do so with

```
mvn clean dependency:tree
# or (mvn 3)
mvn clean org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.1:tree
```

The `clean` is important to avoid any side-effect of old `target` content.

Then, depending on the plugin you are using, you can add exclusion rules as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9807806/6309), in order to avoid those error message.

As seen in [MRUNIT-209](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRUNIT-209), the 2.5.1 version of `dependency-tree` does not run with Maven 3.x.x.
Using the full name `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.1:tree` will force the use of the 3.0.1 version of the maven-dependency-plugin.

Comment: [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:tree (default-cli) @ user-session-consumer ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.internal.Maven3DependencyGraphBuilder
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/graph/DependencyNode

Comment: What version of maven are you using?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.3.9